# setText on numeric TextField forces the application to close

Tags: java, android, string, split

I have been having trouble with setting an initial input on my EditTexts. Whenever I pass an intent containing a string from previous activity, it leads to a forced close.

The main gist of my program is that, a previous activity sends an intent containing a string to the editText activity. If it's not initialized, editTexts are blank, else, they contain the values shown in the TextView from the previous screen. Here is my code:

```
EditText month, day, year;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lab2_082588birthday);

    Intent startUp = getIntent();
    String receivedString = startUp.getStringExtra(Lab2_082588part2.BIRTHDAY_STRING);

    if(receivedString.trim().length() > 0){
        String[] separated = receivedString.split("/");

        int stringMonth = Integer.parseInt(separated[0]);
        int stringDay = Integer.parseInt(separated[1]);
        int stringYear = Integer.parseInt(separated[2]);

        month.setText(stringMonth);
        day.setText(stringDay);
        year.setText(stringDay);

    }
}
```

Here is my **LogCat**

```
07-06 15:05:19.918: E/AndroidRuntime(276): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

07-06 15:05:19.918: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.android.rondrich.Lab2_082588birthday.onCreate(Lab2_082588birthday.java:34)

07-06 15:05:19.918: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

07-06 15:05:19.918: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

Comment: We are not a magician here, Without any piece of code and Error stacktrace. We can't say anything.

Comment: i think you forgot to paste your code. you said: __Here is my code__

Comment: **Here is my code** where is your code???

Comment: Sorry, accidentally pressed enter in the tags area

Comment: Look at my answer, also in comment..

Comment: Finally realized my mistake: I did not initialize receivedString prior to EditText activity so the split delimiter doesn't recognize it. I declared receivedString = " / / ". Also, I did not put an if statement prior to assigning the arrays into respective strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First initialize textView's after 
`setContentView(R.layout.lab2_082588birthday);` as:

```
month = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.month);
 day = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.day);
 month = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.year);
```

and then Set `Integer` Value to `TextView` as:

```
month.setText(stringMonth+"");
day.setText(stringDay+"");
year.setText(stringDay+"");
```

or

```
month.setText(String.valueOf(stringMonth));
day.setText(String.valueOf(stringDay));
year.setText(String.valueOf(stringDay));
```

as after provide logcat:
check array lenth before paring String to int
:

```
if(separated.length >0)
{
        int stringMonth = Integer.parseInt(separated[0]);
        int stringDay = Integer.parseInt(separated[1]);
        int stringYear = Integer.parseInt(separated[2]);

        month.setText(stringMonth+"");
        day.setText(stringDay+"");
        year.setText(stringDay+"");
}
```

Comment: I see, the problem was that I forgot to put if statement before assigning arrays into string. Very dumb of me. Thank you very much!

Comment: i'm  also try many time but when i'm spilting an string  on the basis of "/" string using split("/") then string is not spillted in Array.so try some other Saperator or split("\/") or split regex for spilting string to Array.

Comment: Woops, sorry Mr, imran. First time here in StackOverFlow. I thought the checkmark was meant for multiple answers. Your suggestion has worked. thank you sir

Answer (score 1):

If `receivedString` isn't formatted in a way that ensures it has 2 slashes ("/"), the String array `separated` won't have the 3 values you need.

This will result in an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

**EDIT:**

You must escape the slash character with a backslash `"\/"`.

Comment: I have already taken that into consideration. The prior activity has initialized receivedString as "00/00/0000"

Comment: Your log shows that the error occurred  at line 34. Which line is that in your code?

Comment: int stringMonth = Integer.parseInt(separated[0]); this one

Comment: You must escape the slash character with a backslash `"\/"`,

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this line

```
    month.setText(stringMonth);
    day.setText(stringDay);
    year.setText(stringDay);
```

by bcz stringMonth ,stringDay etc are integer that'y u have to set this way in textview

```
    month.setText(""+stringMonth);
    day.setText(""+stringDay);
    year.setText(""+stringDay);
```

other way is

```
    month.setText(String.valueOf(stringMonth));
    day.setText(String.valueOf(stringDay));
    year.setText(String.valueOf(stringDay));
```